# How do I make it so only people with a role in my server can use the bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to only run a command if they have a role in my server. My bot is in many servers and I want the command to only work if they have a role in a certain server.

I have tried many ways such as:

```
let guildcheck = client.guilds.get('496780648351006720')

if (guildcheck.member.roles.has(role => role.name === 'Role')) {

message.channel.send("works")

}else{

message.channel.send("doesn't work")

}
```

I expected this to make it so if I have "Role" in the guld "496780648351006720" it would reply with "works".

Comment: What is currently wrong with the code; What action it is actually doing right now?

Comment: @Kaynn Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a member property on the guild object? checkout: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-object. From the following endpoint: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (guildcheck.member.roles.has(role => role.name === 'Role'))`
You can't directly get a guild member just by doing `guildcheck.member`, since there are so many members in the guild; The code would be confused as to which member to fetch anyway.

What you were trying to use was probably a [`member(User)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) function, not a property. Following the documentation, you would need to give it a user as an argument, like so:

`if (guildcheck.member(message.author).rol...)`
This way, you can get the message's sender as a guild member.
(Note that `guildcheck.member(message.author)` will be null if the user isn't in the target guild.)

#### Alternatively...

You can do [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) to simply get the message's sender as a guild member
 It would just return null/default if the message wasn't in a guild (Or the user isn't in the server.)

The only issue would be that it now allows any user in a guild to use your command.
You can avoid this by checking against the guild id of where this message was sent in, like so:

```
// Ignore if this is not the desired guild.
if (message.guild.id !== "Your desired guild ID") { return; }

if (message.member.roles.has(role => role.name === 'Role')) {
  message.channel.send("works");
}else{
  message.channel.send("doesn't work");
}
```

Comment: I done some tweaking to this to make it suit me, thanks!